# npm Install not Responding

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I'm following this tutorial on how to work with extensions:
[Github-Page.](https://github.com/Sadraw/Web-Dev-For-Beginners/tree/main/5-browser-extension/1-about-browsers)

While trying to use

> npm install

to get the data from the package.json, I get this and I cannot update the vulnerabilities with `npm audit fix` or `npm audit fix --force` either:

```
up to date, audited 420 packages in 1s
12 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

5 high severity vulnerabilities

To address all issues, run:
  npm audit fix

Run `npm audit` for details.
```

The `main.js` file located in the `dist` folder should be updated after this, but nothing happens. I tried reinstalling `Nodejs` and `npm`, but it didn't work.